# Impossible to collapse <br> in webkit?

Tags: css, cross-browser

As illustrated in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qrbhb/

If you take this markup:

```
<div>There should be no gap between us</div>
<br />
<div>There should be no gap between us</div>
```

and this css:

```
div {
    background: #999;
}

br {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

All webkit based browsers will display a gap equal to the line height of the parent element, while firefox and IEs will not display a gap.  I don't know who is following the spec here, but I can't for the life of me get this to display the same in all browsers and it's driving me crazy.  Any ideas?

**EDIT: Sorry folks, I was looking at a rather complicated layout and mistakenly thought some elements were floating that weren't.  Floated elements behave as expected.**

Comment: Why do you need something like this? I mean, a line break is supposed to... break the line.

Comment: Yes, I think it could be argued that the webkit approach is the correct one, but on the other hand, you could also argue that this behaves more like two line breaks, one that breaks the line and one that adds one line's worth of space before the next element.  I don't really care either way, I'm just trying to get all my browsers to agree. :)

Comment: Crazy idea: Don't put the `<br>` there in the first place :-)

Comment: Actually one `<br />` is just one line break. The second one is imposed by the use of a block element (block elements by default span the whole line, inline elements (such as anchors) don't).

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed out that this is meant to clear floats.  One could use a float-clearing, 0 height empty div to do the same thing, but for some reason this just feels wrong to me.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you're using it to clear floats, [there's no gap](http://jsfiddle.net/qrbhb/47/). If you're not using it to clear floats, what's wrong with `display: none`?

Comment: [This sounds better](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)

Comment: Sorry folks, I was mistakenly trying to clear elements that were not floated, under the impression that they were.  Carry on. :)

Comment: Another way to clear is to give the surrounding `overflow: hidden` (or `auto`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd. I can see some logic to what's going on. It seems to be using the line-height from the preceding element as the height. If you add this, for example, just before the `<br />` as shown:

```
<div class="weird" /><br />
```

...and then set its line-height:

```
div.weird {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

(jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qrbhb/50/))

...then the `<br />` loses its height.

So, I'd guess that the line-break "inherits" -- although that's rather the wrong word -- the height of the preceding bit of text. I'm not certain that's really what's going on, but it makes the most sense of the explanations I can think of.

Really, though, I'm with everyone else -- if you don't want a break between lines, don't use a line-break. If you're going to go a bit non-semantic for clearing stuff anyway, I'd just live with it and use a `<div>`; the practical elements of the web community will understand and forgive you :)

Answer (score 1):

use `display:none;`

http://jsfiddle.net/qrbhb/13/

Comment: [How To Clear Floats Without Structural Markup](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)